# Selecting an appropriate design for Month/Date Selection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a requirement what seemingly looks very simple (and perhaps strange) but some minor details are giving me troubles. Perhaps I'm overthinking this.

I'm building a scheduler application (on WPF) for an embedded device that runs everyday. The scheduler controls when the device can be turned on and off. For example, the embedded device can be scheduled to shut off every weekends and on any holidays, such as July 4th.

So I went ahead and designed my datastructure to hold a datetime collection for holidays. Firstly, I don't need to store the time but apparently in C#, there's no other appropriate class that holds just dates. Second, I also don't need to store years but then I have no way of knowing whether it is a leap year or not. (For example, I can schedule the device to be shut off on every February 29th, but that date may not be available on a particular year.)

I also need a way for the users to select a month/date. As far as I know, there's no appropriate UI control available to handle my problem. I think I need to look for something like this (Below is photoshopped from a standard calendar control):

[image]

What datastructure/design would you use to handle problems like this? What's a good UI design to have users intuitively select a month/date?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear as to how the normal calendar control falls short. Yes, I see that "Every 29th of February" might cause a problem, but wouldn't that only be triggered if it is in fact the 29th of February?

Comment: Weekends and some holidays such as Thanksgiving vary by year.  Just how did you hold a datetime collection for holidays with no year?   March 1 is a Tuesday only 1/7 years.

Comment: @LarsKristensen Because a normal calendar control with a year included gives the user an impression that the scheduler only runs on that particular year/month/date when in fact it needs to run every month/date. Seems like an unintuitive UI design to me.

Comment: @Blam That was my impression as well (hence, why I mentioned it seemed like a strange requirement), but I was told not to necessarily link the dates user may set with actual holidays. If the user wants to only shut off the machine on every May 8th every year, he/she would be able to do so.

Comment: Your proposed design is also not intuitive.  It presents March 1 is a Tuesday.

Comment: @Blam That is just a quick and dirty example I photoshopped. I removed the days for that purpose as well. Just imagine that the March 1st begins on first column. But I'm open for any better suggestions.

Comment: Semi-Offtopic: I just tried adding an event in my Google Calendar on 29th of February 2016 and setting it to "Repeat every year on that date" - which resulted in the event being repeated in 2020. Sounds like you want to implement sort of the same thing?

Comment: @LarsKristensen Yes that sounds pretty close to what I want.

Comment: I would suggest migrating this to http://ux.stackexchange.com/ That community can better help answer the usability repercussions for a year-less calendar.

Comment: @Graham If anything, I'd rather make a separate post for the calendar part. In the worst case, I'm thinking about just using two combo boxes to handle that part (But suggestions for alternatives are most welcome). Design architecture / data structure is the bigger stumble for me and I have a strong feeling that my question won't get answered in ux stackexchange. Plus, the programmer's stackexchange mod moved the question here, so there's a strong chance that this question belongs in this site.

Comment: Take a leave out of how calendar programs do it. Google's calendar is pretty good in this respect, so if you have a Google account, have a look at how the Google Calendar implements recurring events (when editing an event, you need to check the "repeat" checkbox to bring up the modal for the repeat). It does have a calendar component in there. That is used solely for setting the day on which to start the series.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently trying to solve the same problem and decided to model the UI and functionality on the Outlook calendar appointments 'occurrence' feature, simplified a bit. This partially abstracts the selection of repeated events away from a calendar control and covers most scenarios. No point in reinventing the wheel.

The data model is a simple class with type of recurrence(week or month) a day of week flags enum, day of month, recurrence frequency, end date/max number of recurrences.

The tricky bit is processing the recurrence rules (work in progress).